# react-native-ble-manager is not showing Mobile Bluetooth and BLUETOOTH EARPHONES

Tags: react-native, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to implement the Bluetooth service my application. But when scanning is staring my apps to that time not showing Mobile Bluetooth and BLUETOOTH EARPHONES Bluetooth.

Only show without name Bluetooth in console.

Please help this issues.

```dart
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { NativeModules, NativeEventEmitter, View, Text } from 'react-native';
import BleManager from 'react-native-ble-manager';

const BleManagerModule = NativeModules.BleManager;
const bleManagerEmitter = new NativeEventEmitter(BleManagerModule);


export default class App extends Component{
  state = {
    peripherals: new Map(),
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    BleManager.start({ showAlert: false })
  
    this.handlerDiscover = bleManagerEmitter.addListener(
      'BleManagerDiscoverPeripheral',
      this.handleDiscoverPeripheral
    );
  
    this.handlerStop = bleManagerEmitter.addListener(
      'BleManagerStopScan',
      this.handleStopScan
    );
  
    this.scanForDevices(); // I chose to start scanning for devices here
  }
  
  scanForDevices() {
    BleManager.scan([], 30);
  }
  
  handleDiscoverPeripheral = (peripheral) => {
    console.log('Got ble peripheral', peripheral);
    const { peripherals } = this.state;
  
    if (peripheral.name) {
      peripherals.set(peripheral.id, peripheral.name);
    }
    this.setState({ peripherals });
  };

  handleStopScan = () => {
    console.log('Scan is stopped. Devices: ', this.state.peripherals);
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <View>
        <Text>Bluetooth</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [react-native-ble-manager](https://github.com/innoveit/react-native-ble-manager) enables communication between your phone and Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) devices. BLE devices need to advertise their presence to be detected. Keep in mind that BLE is not the same as Bluetooth Classic.

You can only detect BLE devices using [react-native-ble-manager](https://github.com/innoveit/react-native-ble-manager). If you can't find your devices they simply might not be BLE devices but rather Bluetooth Classic devices. Other mobile phones usually do not advertise BLE services and need an app to do so. Bluetooth Headphones might use BLE for some features, but the audio transmission is handled with Bluetooth Classic.

You can use a generic BLE scanner app such as [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Software-and-tools/Development-Tools/nRF-Connect-for-mobile) to scan for BLE devices nearby. The app even allows you to start a GATT server on another phone for it to be accessible using BLE.

Comment: I am also using react-native-ble-manager and have the same problem, scan sometimes found,  sometimes can't find my BLE device.  BLE scanner on app nRF Connect is always found.
 Do you have any solution for this problem?

Comment: @cảnhnguyễn please open a new question and provide as much information as possible

Comment: I scan Bluetooth on my phone device, not see, but scan on BLE scanner on app nRF Connect is always found.

Comment: @cảnhnguyễn as I said, please open a new question. Commenting on an existing question with a different problem does not get you an answer

Comment: Hi @cảnhnguyễn, did u find a solution to this problem? i am facing the same issue. for me it works 3/10 times

Comment: @Dom I still don't have a solution.